# Making fields_for display properly in multistep form partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, nested-forms

I'm inserting `=f.fields_for :customer` in the second partial of a multi step form as described here. It works fine if it's on the first step of the form (_voucher_partial.html.haml), but won't display at all if I move it into the second. Can anyone tell me why, and how to fix? I don't understand why they'd be treated differently by Rails.

Thanks!

## Order

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :customer_attributes, :customer_id, :format

  belongs_to :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
  attr_writer :current_step

  def steps
    %w[voucher recipient delivery confirmation]
  end

  def current_step
    @current_step || steps.first
  end

  def next_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)+1]
  end

  def previous_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)-1]
  end

  def first_step?
    current_step == steps.first
  end

  def last_step?
    current_step == steps.last
  end
```

## OrdersController

```
  # GET /orders/new
  # GET /orders/new.json
  def new
    session[:order_params] ||= {}
    @order = Order.new(session[:order_params])
    @order.build_customer(session[:order_params])
    @order.current_step = session[:order_step]
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    session[:order_params].deep_merge!(params[:order]) if params[:order]
    @order = Order.new(session[:order_params])
    @order.current_step = session[:order_step]
    if params[:back_button]
      @order.previous_step
    elsif @order.last_step?
      @order.save
    else
      @order.next_step
    end
    session[:order_step] = @order.current_step

    if @order.new_record?
      render 'new'
    else
      session[:order_step] = session[:order_params] = nil
      flash[:notice] = "Order saved."
      redirect_to @order
    end
  end
```

## orders/new.html.haml

```
%h1 New order

= form_for(@order) do |f|
  - if @order.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this order from being saved:
      %ul
        - @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg
  = render "#{@order.current_step}_step", :f => f 
  = f.submit "Continue"
  = f.submit "Back", :name => "back_button" unless @order.first_step?

= link_to 'Back', orders_path
```

## _recipient_step.html.haml

```
%h3
  Customer details

=f.fields_for :customer do |builder|
  =builder.label :name
  =builder.text_field :name

  =builder.label :email
  =builder.text_field :email

%h3
  Recipient details

.field
  = f.label :recipient_name
  = f.text_field :recipient_name
```

Comment: Can you post the view in which you add the partials?

Comment: Added, hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try rendering the partials this way:

```
= render partial: "#{@order.current_step}_step", object: @order, locals: { :f => f }
```

**By the way, on your create action, you always create a new Order, but customer is not rebuilt!**

Comment: I've edited the new.html.haml with that code but it's still not showing the fields for the customer...

Comment: Does it render anything from the partial? The "Customer details" header for example?

Comment: Yep, it renders the header, but no fields - the HTML source shows there's nothing on the page.

Comment: Please view my updated post above. On each call of the "create" action you create a new order but its customer field is nil, I believe that this is the problem! You should rebuild the association!

Comment: Hmmm. I tried to add `@order.build_customer(session[:order_params])` into the create action - it's started throwing a new error "Can't mass-assign protected attributes". I've already set these up in the Order model though?

Comment: This is another issue then. You should read the guides about attributes and assignment. Look here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html and specifically the part with the "accepts_nested_attributes_for"